# PHP + Modify string

Tags: php, string, replace, explode

I have got a string and would like to remove everything after a certain "dot"+word combination. For instance:

```
This.Is.A.Test
```

=> would become

```
This.Is.A
```

Comment: I have a very similar function working in javascript (split) and I was searching for a similar one in PHP. I think "explode" might be a good way, but I wasnt able to figure it out from the examples [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Comment: Get the position of ".A" using strpos() and use substr() to get the string result.
Use PHP manual

Comment: Are you trying to remove everything after a *specific* dot+word or just after the *last* dot+word? What if the string was `"This.Is.A.Test."`? Should it just remove the last dot, or does it need to be followed by a word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$str = "This.Is.A.Test"; $str = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, "."));`

Comment: This was the first answer I have tried and it worked just fine!

Answer (score 3):

Were you looking to remove everything after a *specific* dot+word, or just remove the *last* dot+word? If you're looking for a specific word, try this:

```
$str = "This.Is.A.Test";
$find = ".A";
$index = strpos($str, $find);
if ($index !== false)
    $str = substr($str, 0, $index + strlen($find));
echo $str; // "This.Is.A"
```

---

*In response to @SuperSkunk:*

If you wanted to match the whole word, you could do this:

```
$find = ".A.";

$str = "This.Is.A.Test";
$index = strpos($str, $find);
if ($index !== false)
    $str = substr($str, 0, $index + strlen($find) - 1);
echo $str; // "This.Is.A"

$str = "This.Is.AB.Test";
$index = strpos($str, $find);
if ($index !== false)
    $str = substr($str, 0, $index + strlen($find) - 1);
echo $str; // "This.Is.AB.Test" (did not match)
```

Comment: @SuperSkunk: Depends on if that's what the OP is actually looking for. See updated answer.

Comment: Just realized that you would get weird results if `$find` wasn't actually found in the string (meaning `strpos` would return false). Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = explode('.', $str, 4);
array_pop($result);
implode('.', $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll do something very simple like :

```
<?php

$string = 'This.Is.A.Test';

$parts = explode('.', $string);
array_pop($parts); // remove last part
$string = implode('.', $parts);

echo $string;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$pos = strpos($haystack, ".A" );

$result = substr($haystack,0,$pos);

...something like this.